# Draw a big image in center_crop type

Tags: android, performance, imageview

I have a big image(about 2Mb 1024 * 540 ARGB8888) which is got via net. This image will be shown in a ImageView which is 800px width and 400px height in CENTER_CROP scale type. And there are 12 this kind of ImageView in a listview.

My question is:
Does android load the whole image into memory in CENTER_CROP mode cause it is very slow when I slide the listview. Maybe I should clip the image before setImageBitmap()? Which is the efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Read the information from the link bellow. It will help you better to understand how to work with bitmaps in android and even in ListView. You should cash images so you will not download them anytime the ListView is refreshing.And yes,android loads all the image and after that centers it and crops,what you should do is to load in memory only a thumbnail of the all image and display it and not all the image. And as i wrote, you should cash them.

[Android Bitmap managing](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)